# Swift: Display HTML data in a label not display proper image

Tags: html, ios, swift, uilabel, swift4.2

Swift: Display HTML data in a label not display the proper image

Is there any solution?

Thnx in advance, Any help is appreciated.

Till now I am trying by using an NSAttributedString in following way but in this way, the whole HTML display proper but image scale not proper :

Used below code:

```
extension NSAttributedString {
internal convenience init?(html: String) {

    let modifiedFont = String(format:"%@", html)

    guard let data = modifiedFont.data(using: String.Encoding.utf16, allowLossyConversion: false) else {
        // not sure which is more reliable: String.Encoding.utf16 or String.Encoding.unicode
        return nil
    }
    guard let attributedString = try? NSMutableAttributedString(data: data, options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], documentAttributes: nil) else {
        return nil
    }

    self.init(attributedString: attributedString)
}
```

}

[image]

From sever get below HTML to display:

```
<h3><span style="color: #42a48e;">Description</span></h3>
<ul>
<li>Fully tool-less disconnection module with 45&deg; LSA contacts for connecting plastic-insulated copper conductors.</li>
<li>Silicone gel encapsulation gives excellent environmental protection, even in scenarios where the outdoor cabinet is subjected to flooding.</li>
<li>Complete range of accessories makes this an essential part of any FTTN architecture.</li>
</ul>
<h3><span style="color: #42a48e;">Installation Steps:</span></h3>
<ol>
<li>Hold the closed slider with two fingers and then pull the slider fully out until you feel and hear a "click"-sound.</li>
<li>Preparing the wire for installation: When cutting the wire make sure that the cutter is kept straight and don&lsquo;t bend the wire in any direction.</li>
<li>Insert the wire into the highlighted holes until the wire touched the bottom of the connector (about 8-10mm).</li>
<li>Insert the wire fully. Then keep holding/ guiding the wire in position while closing the slider with the second hand.</li>
<li>The slider is closed when you can hear a "click"-sound. Now the wire can be released.</li>
</ol>
<p><img style="max-width: 100%;" src="https://i.imgur.com/EFdLNOc.png" alt="LSA-TL Install Steps" width="100%" height="100%" /></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this issue by using specific `max-width` and `max-height` of image style, See the following code and image for this.

**Note: specify an image `max-width` and `max-height` in px insted of %**

```
<img style='max-width: \(self.view.frame.width - 50)px; max-height: \(self.view.frame.width - 50)px;' src='https://i.imgur.com/EFdLNOc.png' alt='LSA-TL Install Steps' width='100%' height='100%' />
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: HTML display from servers not locally.

Comment: Okay but set max-width and max-height in px from the backend (server) OR replace at your end when you get data from server, (best option is do changes from backend)

Comment: As you said every image max-width and max-height set from backed and change it from my side according to a device. I  don't think is an approrite way to do that change :)

Comment: I just have an issue with image only others than all content display proper.

Comment: Hi, @Ashish fist thing max-width and max-height did not accept in % So you need to give that in the pixel, the second thing how server know our device size? that's why you need to manage at your end.

Comment: I'm not sure but how responsive layout work in a browser according to device size!

Comment: see one of the best option, load HTML in UIWebview

Comment: UIwebview can load image with % and fit as screen width